# "ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number"

Tags: node.js, node-oracledb

I'm trying to execute query on oracle database from nodejs using oracledb client and getting "ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number". I tried multiple suggested way to pass my variable but failed. Query working with hardcode value.

here is my sample code :

```
`# try 1
 var selectStatement = "SELECT * FROM FILEPROCESS_USER where EMAIL like 
 ?";
 # try 2 
var selectStatement = "SELECT * FROM FILEPROCESS_USER where EMAIL like" + EMAIL+;
# try 3
var bindVars = {
    userid : EMAIL,
    resultSet: {dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT, type: oracledb.STRING, maxSize: 
32767},
    error: {dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT, type: oracledb.STRING, maxSize: 4000} } ;
   connection.execute( "SELECT * FROM FILEPROCESS_USER where EMAIL= 
  :userid", bindVars {*



 handleDatabaseOperation( req, res, function (request, response, 
 connection) 
  {
   var EMAIL = 'ABC@GMAIL.COM';
   connection.execute( selectStatement, [email], 
   outFormat: oracledb.OBJECT 
    },function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
       console.log('Error in execution of select statement'+err.message);
       response.writeHead(500, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
       response.end(JSON.stringify({ status: 500, detailed_message: 
       err.message })
       );
       } 
    else {
    response.writeHead (200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    response.end(JSON.stringify(result.rows));
    }
 `
```

getting "ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number" or blank result

Answer (score 0):

Try #1 didn't work because that syntax isn't used by Oracle Database.

Try #2 didn't work for two reasons:
"SELECT * FROM FILEPROCESS_USER where EMAIL like" + EMAIL+;

First, there's no space between "like" and "EMAIL", so they get concatenated together.

Second, it's not using bind variables correctly.

This would have worked:

"SELECT * FROM FILEPROCESS_USER where EMAIL like :EMAIL";

Try #3 didn't work because you have one bind variable in the SQL but you supplied multiple bind variable values.

Comment: Just following up... If you've not seen this series, you may find it useful: https://jsao.io/2018/03/creating-a-rest-api-with-node-js-and-oracle-database/

Comment: Ok let me try and confirm you